# I am trying to write a batch that pulls variables from 2 text files

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to write a batch that pulls variables from 2 text files. So far I can only get one variable working from one text file at a time.

I need to set variables for a remote PC name, and the user name on the PC so I can copy the desktop. I currently can get all the user profiles desktops copied one PC at a time by entering the pc name at the prompt, then having the batch pull the all user names from the text file.

What I am really looking for is to be able to set the multiple pc name as one variable in a .txt file, and the user profile list as a second variable, both in .txt files.

```
PCList.txt would contain something like
Workstation1
Workstation2

UserProfileList.txt would contain something like
Bob
Jane
Cindy
```

The code I am using now to set the single PC name and have the user profiles pull from a .txt is-

```
SET /P variable=PCname:

for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\username\Desktop\Program\PCLOGS\%variable%\%variable%_UserProfileList.txt) do xcopy /H /E /Y /I "\\%variable%\C$\Documents and Settings\%%A\Desktop" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Program\PCLOGS\%variable%\UserProfiles\%%A\Desktop"
```

I have been looking for a solution for a while and have not found one. Any help would be appericated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Make an example, or explain better.

Comment: Are the users Bob Jane Cindy on both workstations1 and 2?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F "delims=" %%V in (PCList.txt) do (
   for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (C:\Users\username\Desktop\Program\PCLOGS\%%V\%%V_UserProfileList.txt) do (
      xcopy /H /E /Y /I "\\%%V\C$\Documents and Settings\%%A\Desktop" "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Program\PCLOGS\%%V\UserProfiles\%%A\Desktop"
   )
)
```

Comment: Aacini thanks for the answer I will have to wait until Monday to test it. Than you!

Comment: @ECS: If you think this answer solved your problem, you may accept it as Best answer. Thanks...